# How to getChildren more than once and save the parent node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Assume my database has the following structure:

```
data
 |___randomId1
 |       |_________randomData1
 |                       |______Key1: value
 |                       |______Key2: value
 |___randomId2
         |_________randomData2
                         |______Key1: value
                         |______Key2: value
```

And I want to iterate to get all values, and also save the parent id (randomId1, randomId2). How can I loop through? right now I have the following:

```
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               // what to put here to get the values and also save the ids?
        }
    }
```

You see that each `randomData` has the same map (Key1 and Key2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, you need use two nested loops like in the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference dataRef = rootRef.child("data");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String parentKey = dSnapshot.getKey();

            for(DataSnapshot ds : dSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String key = ds.getKey();

                String key1 = ds.child("Key1").getValue(String.class);
                String key2 = ds.child("Key2").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, key1 + " / " + key2);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
dataRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```